# iOS 7 popViewControllerAnimated shifting entire view upwards

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

Running into an issue only on iOS 7. On one screen I have a back button that returns to a tableview. That back button's code is `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` but I'm seeing an issue where all of the content on the screen I go back to is shifting up when i click back (the content shifts to where its supposed to be, but open first viewing it after clicking back, its lower on screen than it should be and then slides up). Previously in iOS 6, it did the animation you'd expect, the left to right movement of the old and new screen, but the content shifting up is new and I can't figure out what's causing it. I set the animated to NO and while that does stop it, I also lose the left to right I want and it looks very jerky going screen to screen. Any thoughts on how to just get the normal left to right slide without it shifting my content?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two VC ,VC1 and VC2 if you are using on VC2.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Check you xib of VC1 you need to take Navigation Bar at top.**

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response, but I'm a little confused. the code is the line i have already. can you clarify what you're saying about the view controllers?

Comment: You  just need to add a UINavigationBar at the top in XIB/nib file in UI.

Comment: i have acustom nav bar i build programmatically, I'm not sure if i can add one to nib. do you know how this will fix the shift of the content? it looks like its happening between viewwillappear and viewdidappear

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an AutoLayout issue. Make sure AutoLayout is turned off, and add the following to your viewDidLoad:

```
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help. i have auto layout off for my nib and i added that line, but I'm still seeing the bizarre shift up of everything and i can tell its happening between viewwillappear and viewdidappear.

Comment: Another thing it could be is that the Nav Bar is translucent in iOS 7: Try to set your navigation bar to be non-translucent: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]

Comment: thanks natasha, that unfortunately didn't do it. i inherited a lot of this so there may be something buried somewhere ill have to find. one note is that i am using 6.1 as base sdk because i need to for now. when i change to 7 it goes away